# Results differ when i have iostream and when i don't, but no error

Tags: c++, output, iostream

I tried to do a little something today and i got a very weird behaviour from my code. When i leave #include  in the code the result differs from when i make it a comment. Maybe somebody could take a look and tell me why, i would appreciate.

Behaviour mentioned above works in certain data sets. Here is the code and my data set.

```
26 13
X           X
XXXXXXX  X  X
X        X  X
X  X     X  X
X  X    RX  X
X  XXXXXXX  X
X           X
X XX XXXXX  X
XXXX XX  X  X
X        X  X
X  X     X  X
X  X     X  X
X  XXXXXXX  X
X           X
X X XXXXXX  X
XXX XXX  X  X
X        X  X
X  X     X  X
X  X     X  X
X  XXXXXXX  X
X           X
X X XXX XX  X
X X XX XXXX X
X X XX X    X
X XX        X
J    XXX XXXX
```

---

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX 101

using namespace std;

struct leeR
{
    int x, y;
}c[MAX*MAX], ir, ij;

int R[MAX][MAX], J[MAX][MAX];
int n, m, dx[] = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1 }, dy[] = { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1 };

void read()
{
    freopen ( "rj.in", "r", stdin );
    scanf ( "%d%d%c", &n, &m, &R[1][1] );
    char w;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i )
        for ( int j = 1; j <= m + 1; ++j )
        {
            scanf ( "%c", &w );
            if ( w == 'R' )
                ir.x = i, ir.y = j;
            else if ( w == 'J' )
                ij.x = i, ij.y = j;
            else if ( w == 'X' )
                R[i][j] = -1;
            J[i][j] = R[i][j];
        }
    fclose(stdin);
}

void dump()
{
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= m; ++j )
            printf ( "%d ", R[i][j] );
        printf ( "\n\n" );
    }
    printf ( "\n\n" );
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i )
    {
        for ( int j = 1; j <= m; ++j )
            printf ( "%d ", J[i][j] );
        printf ( "\n\n" );
    }
}

void leeR()
{
    int p(0), f(1);
    c[1] = ir;
    R[ir.x][ir.y] = 1;
    do
    {
        ++p;
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 7; ++i )
            if ( c[p].x + dx[i] > 0 && c[p].y + dy[i] > 0 && !R[c[p].x + dx[i]][c[p].y + dy[i]] )
                R[ c[p].x + dx[i] ][ c[p].y + dy[i] ] = R[c[p].x][c[p].y] + 1,
                c[++f].x = c[p].x + dx[i],
                c[f].y = c[p].y + dy[i];
        if ( p == f )
            break;
    }while ( f != p + 1 );
}

void leeJ()
{
    int p(0), f(1);
    c[1] = ij;
    J[ij.x][ij.y] = 1;
    do
    {
        ++p;
        for ( int i = 0; i <= 7; ++i )
            if ( c[p].x + dx[i] <= n && c[p].y + dy[i] <= m && c[p].x + dx[i] > 0 && c[p].y + dy[i] > 0 && !J[c[p].x + dx[i]][c[p].y + dy[i]] )
                J[ c[p].x + dx[i] ][ c[p].y + dy[i] ] = J[c[p].x][c[p].y] + 1,
                c[++f].x = c[p].x + dx[i],
                c[f].y = c[p].y + dy[i];
        if ( p == f )
            break;
    }while ( f != p + 1 );
}

void check()
{
    freopen ( "rj.out", "w", stdout );
    int X, Y, M(200000);
    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i )
        for ( int j = 1; j <= m; ++j )
            if ( R[i][j] == J[i][j] && R[i][j] < M && R[i][j] > 0 )
                M = R[i][j], X = i, Y = j;
    printf ( "%d %d %d\n", X, Y, M );
    fclose(stdout);
}

int main()
{
    read();
    leeR();
    leeJ();
    check();
    //dump();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how does the output differ ? What error do you mean when you say "Error mentioned above" ?

Comment: Try commenting the #include <iostream>, you might get different results. By error i meant the different results.

Comment: I dont know by heart the correct links, maybe the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) would be a good start to read for you. Your question should explain what is the problem. Of course it is good when your question includes all code necessary to reprocude the problem, but this should not be the only way for readers to find out what is going wrong. Please edit the question to include expected output and actual output (maybe not in full but at least decribe what is going wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try:

`g++ test.cpp -fsanitize=address -g -O0 -std=c++11`
This allows you to receive an error when "something bad" happens.

Then, load the program up in GDB:

`gdb ./a.out
break __asan_report_error
run
backtrace`

At this point, I see that on (or about) line 62, you have a buffer overflow:

`if ( c[p].x + dx[i] > 0 && c[p].y + dy[i] > 0 && !R[c[p].x + dx[i]][c[p].y + dy[i]] )`

At this point, you can do `info locals`. For me, it prints:

`(gdb) info locals
i = 3
p = 7937
f = 8119`

Now, I'm not about to debug this *for* you but this should be enough for you to figure out where your logic is going wrong.

Comment: how does the logic of the code change by removing an `#include <iostream>` ? I think this is what the OP was asking for

Comment: "buffer overflow" means that the logic didn't change; the data it was given did. Welcome to "undefined behavior 101"